# Is it possible okay to use regression MLP for ordinal classification problem when target variable is numerical?

Tags: python, classification, regression, mlp

I have a target variable of 1-10 that represent difficulty level. These are individual classes represented by integers with 1 being the easiest and 10 most difficult. I have decided to use regression MLP because I wish the model to understand ordinality. Eg if the observed outcome was 5 I want the model to understand that a predicted value of 6 is much better than say 1 which would not be the case in standard classification MLP. When making predictions in the test data I have then rounded the results to 0 decimal places with following code:

```
y_test_pred = model6.predict(X_test2)
y_test_pred=np.round(y_test_pred,0)
```

Is this a valid way of tackling the problem?